# Custom thumbnail grid 3 columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get this to work, I found [this](http://www.bootply.com/utGXpeBgE2).

Instead of 4 columns, I want to keep the same height for 3 columns. How can I do this?

This is how it looks on my frontend:

[x http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/661/TS8KVU.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/661/TS8KVU.png)

And it should be at 100% of the screen side by side images.

Comment: show your markup here by editing the question.

Comment: It looks like this: http://www.bootply.com/q6Zk4nXjKa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this? or you want the image fill the div?:

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-pad">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1280x640/eee">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 no-pad">
 <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1280x640/eee">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 no-pad">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1280x640/eee">
</div>

.no-pad{
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
        height:381px;
}

.no-pad img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the width is not the same for the 3 images, here is my bootply: http://www.bootply.com/q6Zk4nXjKa

Comment: here is the css:
    .no-pad{
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
  height:381px;
}

.no-pad img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
 }

Comment: it worked, but still i needed to edit some of my css. Thanks!